# Persistence layer as microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I'm a beginner in microservice architecture and I have read in a lot of blog that in a microservice architecture, it is mandatory that each micro service has its own database. In my case it may cost very expensive.

My question is, is it possible to make the persistence layer as micro service in itself ? Which would have the function of allowing other microservices to have read/write access to the database.
Thanks

Comment: That would at least partially violate some microservice architecture benefits as if that one service goes down then so does everything that needs DB access.

Comment: You could have thousands of microservices sharing a highly available "database" with one "tenant" or schema for each microservice. Besides that microservices are not compulsory t

Comment: You can, but if several micro services need access to a single database, you might want to redesign the services and try to restructure your micro services.  After all, micro services is architecture style and without any strict boundaries as to what can constitute a micro service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question first of all lets understand :

> it is mandatory that each micro service has its own database. In my
>   case it may cost very expensive.

Yes it is said that every microservice should have its own database.

What they mean is tables/collection of each microservice should be separate (you could use a single scalable database instance) and one microservice should only access the data of other microservices only through API calls

Benefits of having a separate model are:

1. Model will be clean. Eg: In E-Commerce Customer have diff. meaning for Shipping Microservice, Order Microservice, Customer Management Microservice and so on. If we put all data required by multiple microserives Customer Object will become very big
2. Microservices could evolve independently. In this case if we have a single Customer object and one microservice lets say Order one want to add something to the schema, all microservices needs to change

If we have a single Database Schema we will be getting into a big mess.

> In my case it may cost very expensive.

If expensive means read model actually require data from multiple microservices. then its better to listen to events from multiple microservices and create a single read model , little duplication of data is ok.

If anything else, ask more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Having all Microservices accessing the same database will result in Loose Cohesion and Strong Coupling

Try to see if you can define separate Schema for each of the Microservices, so that you can ensure Microservices doesn't refer to the tables of other MicroServices.

This way in future, you can seamlessly move to separate Database for each service when your infrastructure cost concern goes off.

Answer (score 0):

Micro services follows database per service model

Comment: No, Microservice boundaries can be one of 3 types 1) Private-Table(s)-per-service   2) Schema-per-service 3) Database-server-per-service